# InfoBox won't load HTML content

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infobox

I am trying to use the Google Map API (V3) to drop pins on a map. I am able to place the pin and open an info box. Unfortunately the info box won't display HTML content, only a string. I am using the following code to create/display my pin/info box.

```js
addMarker('1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC');

function addMarker(address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            var boxText = document.createElement("div");
            boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
            boxText.innerHTML = "Hello World!";

            var myOptions = {
                 content: boxText
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
                ,zIndex: null
                ,boxStyle: { 
                  backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
                  ,width: "280px"
                 }
                ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                ,isHidden: false
                ,pane: "floatPane"
                ,enableEventPropagation: false
            };

            var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                if( ib.anchor === this ){
                    ib.close();
                }
                else {
                    ib.open(map, this);
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

When doing this, the infobox contents are always `[object HTMLDivElement]` and I can not figure out how to have it properly display the informationfound in `boxText`. The code for the info box is taken almost 100% straight from Google's own example.

Comment: your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Aqvba/

Comment: Well, this makes it much more difficult to diagnose then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is incredibly simple. Use the most up-to-date version of infobox.js and it works fine.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  I'm using the latest version but still experiencing the same [object HtmlDivElement] string issue